Seeking a Well-Established Solana Developer to Assist with Blowfish Whitelisting Process for My Dapp
Hello Solana Community,
I’ve recently completed development of my Dapp, but I encountered a warning message from the Phantom wallet, which advised users that my site may be potentially malicious. I’ve already taken the necessary step of contacting Blowfish and have initiated the review process. I was completely transparent in my communication, providing all details about myself, my team, and the project.
However, I understand that having a well-established and trusted developer within the Solana community vouch for my project could significantly smooth this process. Therefore, I am seeking the assistance of an experienced Solana developer who is willing to help me with this.
I’m ready to provide any details necessary about my project, team, and process.
I am fully prepared to compensate for your time and assistance.
If needed, I’m open to planning a call to discuss the details in depth.
If you are a well-respected developer in the Solana community and are interested in helping me with this, please reach out. Your expertise and support would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Did you ever get this sorted out? I’m in same position
